# AWC: 2 hostnames on EC2 instance from custom AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-ami

I am pre-baking an AMI from which to launch some instances;

The only networking configuration I make, is to add a custom dns as follows:

prepend domain-name-servers 10.3.4.1;

in the ami's `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`;

Then, in an instance I launch from this ami:

```
root@ip-10-17-0-114:~# cat /etc/hostname
ip-10-17-0-15
root@ip-10-17-0-114:~# hostname
ip-10-17-0-114
```

Is this behavior normal?

Answer (score 1):

In your AMI, file `/etc/sysconfig/network` ensure hostname is set to the below:
`HOSTNAME=localhost.localdomain` and `NETWORKING=yes`

Comment: this file does not exist at least on `debian jessie`

Answer (score 0):

domain-name-server 10.3.4.1 is not the same as hostname. Would need some more info to actually help. If you area trying to point your EC2 instances DNS server setting to that IP address, you could do that in the DHCP options within a VPC.

what are you trying to achieve here?